# Checkbox in angular issue

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I define a checkbox in angular like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" ng-model="model.rememberMe" value="1" />
```

and in my `controller` i have :

```
  app.controller('loginController', function ($http, $scope) {

    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.model.rememberMe = $scope.rememberMe == undefined ? false : true;       
        $http.post("/Accounts/UserLogin", $scope.model).success(function (response) {
            $scope.message = response;
        });
    }
});
```

but in console i have an error :`Cannot set property 'rememberMe' of undefined`, what is the problem?

Comment: Hard guess you didnt define `$scope.model`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define directly

```
$scope.model.rememberMe
//$scope.model is not defined (=undefined), therefore you get :
//Cannot set property 'rememberMe' of undefined
```

you have to do

```
$scope.model = {};  //define object "model"
$scope.model.rememberMe = ... //set property rememberMe of "model"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your controller should be:

```
 app.controller('loginController', function ($http, $scope) {
    $scope.model = { rememberMe: false };
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.model.rememberMe = $scope.rememberMe == undefined ? false : true;       
        $http.post("/Accounts/UserLogin", $scope.model).success(function (response) {
            $scope.message = response;
        });
    }
});
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot to declare the $scope.model.

First:

> $scope.model = {};

After:

> $scope.model.rememberMe = $scope.rememberMe == undefined ? false : true;